# Flattening nested lists in Lua

Tags: arrays, indexing, lua

Suppose I have a list that looks like this:

```lua
{{'text'}, {'something', 'string'}, {'thing'}}
```

I want to turn this into the following list:

```lua
{'text', 'something', 'string', 'thing'}
```

"flattening" the nested lists.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how could I get each individual string as an index"? Do you want to "flatten" the table to `{'text', 'something', 'string', 'thing'}`?

Comment: The way it is now, 'string' would have an index of [2][2], but I would like to get it as an index of 3 because it's the third element in the entire array, then apply the same logic to the entire array without changing the structure of it.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for flattening, got it. Just with a "depth" of 2? E.g. what should happen with `{"foo", {{"bar"}}}` - should that become `{"foo", "bar"}` or `{"foo", {"bar"}}`?

Answer (score 2):

This operation is called *flattening*. It turns "nested" lists like `{{'text'}, {'something', 'string'}, {'thing'}}` into a "flat" list `{'text', 'something', 'string', 'thing'}`. A deep flattening can straightforwardly be written as follows:

```lua
function flatten(v)
    local res = {}
    local function flatten(v)
        if type(v) ~= "table" then
            table.insert(res, v)
            return
        end
        for _, v in ipairs(v) do
            flatten(v)
        end
    end
    flatten(v)
    return res
end
```

Usage:

```lua
print(table.unpack(flatten{{'text'}, {'something', 'string'}, {'thing'}})) -- text  something   string  thing
```